# Hibrenate not working in Java Dynamic Project and same code works on JavaProject

Tags: hibernate

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/web-application-with-hibernate
I had implemented same with  changes in configuration file as per DB

Comment: Same code with minor changes were implemented in Java Project that is running quite smoothly but in Dynamic Web Project it throws the above mentioned errors.

Comment: Can you tell me where had you put up your hibernate configurations files ?